ReactJs Application to use Lightning ClickToDial Component
In my ReactJs Application, I am trying to implement a salesforce click-to-dial component within a React functional component . How can this be done? I am using Yarn.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-click-to-dial/example

I did the following attempt:
yarn add @lwc/engine
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';


Error: Cannot find module 'lwc' or its corresponding type
declarations.ts(2307)

